# SourcePollingChannelAdapter register bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I dynamic create `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`. After add new url into db, i create new instance of `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` andd start it.
Here code:

```
public SourcePollingChannelAdapter getAdapter(RssStream rssStream) throws MalformedURLException {
    String beanIdAdapter = "adapter." + rssStream.getId();
    String beanIdSource = "source." + rssStream.getId();
    SourcePollingChannelAdapter adapter;
    if (context.containsBean(beanIdAdapter)) {
      adapter = (SourcePollingChannelAdapter) context.getBean(beanIdAdapter);
    }
    else {

      URL url = new URL(rssStream.getLink());
      FeedEntryMessageSource source = new FeedEntryMessageSource(url, "news");
      source.setApplicationContext(context);
      source.setBeanName("source");
      source.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
      source.afterPropertiesSet();

      adapter = new SourcePollingChannelAdapter();
      adapter.setApplicationContext(context);
      adapter.setBeanName(beanIdAdapter);
      adapter.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
      adapter.setSource(source);
      adapter.setOutputChannel(channel);
      adapter.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(5000));
      adapter.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
    return adapter;
  }
```

But, after delete url from db, i need stop and delete `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`.

```
public void deleteAdapter(int id) {
    final String beanId = "adapter." + id;
    if (context.containsBean(beanId)) {
      SourcePollingChannelAdapter adapter = (SourcePollingChannelAdapter) context.getBean(beanId);
      adapter.stop(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          BeanDefinitionRegistry beanDefinitionRegistry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory;
          beanDefinitionRegistry.removeBeanDefinition(beanId);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

I create new adaptar, start it and I try to delete. But i got `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register the bean

```
if (beanFactory instanceof ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) {
    ((ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) beanFactory).registerSingleton(
        beanIdAdapter, adapter);
}
```

Although the framework does so, you don't really need to register the source (unless you also need to access it later).

**EDIT:**

However, the framework is not really designed for this activity - it would be better to keep the references in your own class. See [this note](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/90493f49e628929b2d83ac564c0e5a6e8d524875).